# How to use a Google service account on a Reactjs Firebase project for using APIs?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to integrate a Google service account to my reactjs-Firebase project but I seem to not understand how to do it.

**What I have tried:**

I selected JSON as my KEY type for the service account and downloaded it to my system and tried to set it using Application default credentials. (didn't work)

but nothing seems to work.
and I don't understand how to use the service account to call API in this react-firebase project.
am I supposed to authenticate it using Application default credentials or some other method.

Expected result: Want to integrate service account to my reactjs-firebase project so that I can call API's without an API key

Actual result: not able to do that.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you saying you want to bundle a service account into your frontend code?  That's generally a bad idea, since service accounts are privileged, and if they're accessible to the public via your app, they can be used to run up charges on your account by accessing billed services.

Comment: so there is no way I can integrate a service account with reactjs-firebase project in a safe manner?

Comment: Since service accounts are privileged, it's never really "safe" to make its data available to the world via a web or mobile app. Consider using a backend instead.

Comment: Is it possible to put it in firebase backend to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You should never put a service account embedded on your front-end or any other secrets as anyone using developer tools in browser can see them.
The best approach for you should be the end user providing their credentials that need to be authenticated against your backend. In the backend if the user is authorized you can have access the service account information and make the calls you need.

Specifically on your Firebase you should use the Cloud Secret Manager and access if like this:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { defineSecret } = require('firebase-functions/params');
const serviceAccount = defineSecret('SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY');
// get other secrets and do whatever you need...
```

There is a tutorial [here](https://fireship.io/lessons/secret-manager-with-firebase/) on secrets.

Or you can go straight to the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/reference/rest).