# How to integrate a google service account in a firebase project directly?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to integrate a google service account to a firebase project for a web application.
How can I integrate it to firebase project directly(to the backend) so that I can use APIs without API-key

Comment: It seems that you mostly just reposted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58621355/how-to-use-a-google-service-account-on-a-reactjs-firebase-project-for-using-apis

Answer (score 0):

By using Firebase in your project, you get access to a set of client-side APIs that you can use directly in your application without needing to include the Google Service Account. Most Firebase products rely on a separate user-authentication mechanism, and their own server-side security rules language to control what data each user has access to. So there should be no need to include the Google Service Account credentials in your application code.

If you have a specific Google API for which no Firebase SDK exists, you can call that API from something like Cloud Functions. In Cloud Functions you can securely use your service account, and then expose just the required functionality to your application code.